# TinyMCE push down submenus using fixed_toolbar_container

Tags: tinymce

I'm using the developer version of TinyMCE version 4.1.5 and I'm having problems with the submenus when using fixed_toolbar_container. The submenus are being pushed down at the bottom of the page. What should I do so that it would appear as if they're in the same container even if the divs generated for the submenus are appended at the end of the page.

Here's a screenshot and I've highlighted the part where the submenus appear:
http://i61.tinypic.com/vdq2iu.png