# TinyMce submenu's not sticking to toolbar when using fixed_toolbar_container and absolute position

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

We would like to have a greater control of where and how we position the tinymce toolbar. We found this option fixed_toolbar_container which solves a lot for us but brings us an anoying problem. The documents say the fixed_toolbar_container (http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:fixed_toolbar_container) can be used to have a fixed toolbar. But we actually would like to use it to be absolute so we can position it relative to it's container.

I created a JS Fiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ronfmLym/2/. When you open the  toolbar by clicking on the text the toolbar will be positioned absolute. When you open a submenu (i.e. by clicking on "file") a submenu will open. Now when you start scrolling the submenu won't stick to the toolbar. This is because these submenu's get the mce-fixed class because we set the fixed_toolbar_container property.

```
<div class="element">
    <div class="toolbar-container"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make the submenu's stick to the toolbar when positioned absolute and scrolling? Keep in mind that we are switching to a fixed positioning when the toolbar is going off screen.

We  thought we could maybe fix it by modifying the container element of de submenu's by using the piece of code below and overwriting the top-position of the submenu's and setting  the positioner to absolute with css. But that seems to mess up the tooltips and tinymce doesn't recalculate the "left" css-property of the submenu's so the position in still off.

```
tinymce.ui.Control.prototype.getContainerElm = function() {
    return document.getElementById('toolbar-container');
};
```

The only corresponding question I could find on stackoverflow was this one: [TinyMCE push down submenus using fixed_toolbar_container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520837/tinymce-push-down-submenus-using-fixed-toolbar-container), no answers there.

Answer (score 4):

Tried wrapping the toolbar in a div and using `position:relative;` to try and hack it together, but didn't cooperate this time.

It appears that the toolbar actually is accounting for its position at the time of click. So your only conflict is if the opened toolbar is `position:absolute` and then changes to `position:fixed` or vice versa.

Your best [manual] bet would be to call a function at the same time that you change the position of the toolbar that:

1. Detects if any menus are open.
2. Changes the toolbar position.
3. Reopens the menus that were open.

The lazy (discouraged) fix would be to close all submenus whenever the position changes. This will fix the layout, but it will require the user to click once again to bring the menu back.

Sorry this isn't a silver bullet answer :(

Comment: The code to recompute the positioning is thus present in their code base. The question is: is there a (public) function in the API to do this? 

If so, we could write a custom theme that registers some extra events (scroll most importantly) and then executes this method.

Comment: Have you thoughts how one could do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. All the forums seem to recommend creating a new editor or initializing the old one if it needs to move:

"Moving the editor will break it. Either create a new one each time, or you could reinitialize the editor, which is slightly more complex.

This should get you started. http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=114742 Make sure you read all the way to the bottom. There needs to be an event listener or timer before you reinitialize with the same id."

Answer (score 0):

This answer follows *Brian John's* suggestion:

I'm using this method to position any open `mce-floatpanel` (This is typescript, but it shouldn't be too hard to convert to ES or whatever you need.):

```
   positionTinyMceDropdowns() {
        // TODO: You'll need to replace all occurrences 
        // of this.mceWrapperElement with whatever is
        // wrapping your TinyMCE. If you have only a 
        // single instance, you can just replace it
        // with document
        const button = <HTMLElement> this.mceWrapperElement.getElementsByClassName('mce-opened').item(0);
        const items = document.getElementsByClassName('mce-floatpanel');

        let wrapperNode: HTMLElement;
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            const currentItem = <HTMLElement> items.item(i);
            if (currentItem.style.display !== 'none') {
                wrapperNode = currentItem;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!wrapperNode || !button) {
            return;
        }

        const styles = wrapperNode.style;
        styles.display = 'block';
        styles.position = 'absolute';

        const bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
        const buttonRect = button.getBoundingClientRect();

        // get absolute button position:
        let y   = buttonRect.top - bodyRect.top;
        y += 33; // toolbar line height;

        styles.top = `${Math.floor(y)}px`;
    }
```

The instances I found in which it needs to be called:

- on window scroll (or if the editor is wrapped in a scrolling container, then whenever *that* scrolls)
- on window resize (or if the editor is wrapped in a container that resizes without the window being resized, then whenever *that container* is resized)

So here's a sample for the simplest case in angular (again, adept to whichever js framework you're using):

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

// ...

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    public onResize() {
        this.positionTinyMceDropdowns();
    }
```

Interestingly on iOS devices (and perhaps other mobile devices?) `mce-floatpanel` wasn't even positioned correctly after it had just been opened. So I had to add this:

```
tinymceConfig.setup = (editor: TinyMceEditor) => {
    editor.on('init', () => {
        const panel = this.mceWrapperElement.querySelector('.mce-tinymce.mce-panel');
        if (panel) {
            panel.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
                this.positionTinyMceDropdowns();
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the config setting `fixed_toolbar_container` is poorly explained in TinyMCE 6 documentation but when you correctly configure it, you'll find it will work much more nice (especially for `inline` mode) than the default configuration that tries to emulate `position:sticky`.

In practice, you want to `fixed_toolbar_container` set to a string that's CSS selector for the container, typically something like `"#mycontainer"`.

After that, you can move the container element using its CSS properties, the TinyMCE user interface nicely follows around. (Modulo typical TinyMCE bugs, of course. For example, the submenus overflow to right with very narrow viewports.)

Note that TinyMCE positions stuff where it uses `position:absolute` relative to `fixed_toolbar_container` container and if you move that container around, in some cases you must execute `editor.dispatch("ResizeWindow")` to trigger TinyMCE to re-calculate the absolutely positioned elements.

See demo using custom container with `position:sticky` at https://jsfiddle.net/8bndv26t/1/.